# мне надо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки(goal), в tableView(tableview) выводился текст из label(secondlabel) помогите пожалуйста

Tags: swift, button, таймер, tableview, label

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var goal: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var secondLabel: UILabel!
 
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
private var timer: Timer!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
    

     
     timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1,
                                  target: self,
                                  selector: #selector(countSeconds(_:)),
                                  userInfo: nil,
                                  repeats: true)
 }
 
 @objc func countSeconds(_ sender: Timer) {
     let date = Date()
     let calendar = Calendar.current
     let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
     let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
     let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
     let hourString = String(hour)
     let minutesString = String(minutes)
     let secondsString = String(seconds)
     
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.secondLabel.text = hourString + ":" + minutesString + ":" + secondsString
     }
 }
@IBAction func goal(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
```

}